# ORB save video frame if object is detected

Tags: android, algorithm, opencv, brute-force, orb

I'm working on an Android app that uses ORB algorithm to find an object in the video stream received from the camera. What I'm trying to do is save the video frame where the object appears. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I save all the video frames, even though the object is not in the image. Here is my code:

```
//partea de feature description si matching
    int maximumNuberOfMatches=10;
    Mat greyInputImage=new Mat();
    Mat frameToMatch=cameraFrameRgba;

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mInputImage, greyInputImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frameToMatch, cameraFrameGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints=new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keyPointsToMatch=new MatOfKeyPoint();

    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    detector.detect(greyInputImage, keyPoints);
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(greyInputImage, keyPoints, greyInputImage);
    // displayImage(greyImage);

    detector.detect(greyInputImage, keyPoints);
    detector.detect(cameraFrameGray, keyPointsToMatch);

    DescriptorExtractor dExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

    Mat descriptors=new Mat();
    Mat descriptorsToMatch=new Mat();

    dExtractor.compute(greyInputImage, keyPoints, descriptors);
    dExtractor.compute(cameraFrameGray, keyPointsToMatch, descriptorsToMatch);
 DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
    MatOfDMatch matches=new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptorsToMatch,descriptors,matches);
    ArrayList<DMatch> goodMatches=new ArrayList<DMatch>();
    List<DMatch> allMatches=matches.toList();

    double minDist = 100;
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptorsToMatch.rows(); i++ )
    {
        double dist = allMatches.get(i).distance;
        if( dist < minDist ) minDist = dist;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptorsToMatch.rows() && goodMatches.size()
            <maximumNuberOfMatches; i++ )
    {
        if(allMatches.get(i).distance<= 2*minDist)
        {
            goodMatches.add(allMatches.get(i));
        }
    }
    MatOfDMatch goodEnough=new MatOfDMatch();
    goodEnough.fromList(goodMatches);
    Mat finalImg=new Mat();
    Features2d.drawMatches(cameraFrameGray, keyPointsToMatch, mInputImage, keyPoints, goodEnough, finalImg, Scalar.all(-1),Scalar.all(-1),new MatOfByte(), Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS + Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    int w = 1920, h = 1080;

    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
    Bitmap imageToStore = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap

    Utils.matToBitmap(cameraFrameGray,imageToStore);
```

I've included the matching part, because I assume that there is the part where I'm doing the mistake. The Bitmap imageToStore is the image where i want to save the video frame.

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding something like this: `if(goodMatches>some value)` then save image... but with what value should I test?

Comment: typically you can't use the number of good matches directly, because you dont have information about how many good matches are available in good or bad images (it can vary very much). One approach could be to compute a homography. If this is possible and describes the object well, you might assume it to be detected.But depending on your desired correctness, this task might be not trivial at all ;)